# How do you package HTML applications for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, webapps

[Gomobile](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) talks about HTML5 applications but doesn't explain how to package or install them on Ubuntu Phone/Touch.

Is the "Unity Webapps" stuff [webapps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/) the same for Ubuntu Touch? (API documentation [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/javascript/unity-web-api-reference.html) appears to be missing.)

Or are there any differences we should be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/javascript/uwapi-ref.html) seems to be the correct link.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) you will find more informations about the development of apps to Ubuntu Phone/Tablet:

[Here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/tutorials/cordova-camera-app-tutorial/) you find a specific example of a HTML application for Ubuntu Touch:

And [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/) is about packaging:

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise just use comments.

Comment: A couple of your links appear to be broken..

Comment: @Seth since the post is from March 2014 this can happen. Just head over to the official web page developer.ubuntu.com. There you find all answers. Just go through their navigation and use Google.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but if you are using QT Creator, there is an option under Build->Ubuntu Touch->Create Application Package I haven't tested it out but I think it creates a deb package.

There has been news about the Ubuntu Development team proposing a new packaging format which mainly targets Ubuntu phone and tablets. :  [UBUNTU MIGHT GET A NEW SIMPLIFIED PACKAGING FORMAT AND APP INSTALLER](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/ubuntu-might-get-new-simplified.html)